# previous args shortcuts?

Tags: bash

In bash, I know of 3 "args from previous command" shortcuts.  They are:

1. **!^**  →  first arg, spaces preserved;
2. **$_**  →  last arg, spaces **not** preserved;
3. **!***  →  all args, spaces preserved;

So are there any more arg vars/shortcuts like that? :)

---

the **$_** is useful when I call a file with one command, that's say in a different [long named] directory, then want to call it again in my next command [i.e. `$ stat a\ b\ c/sub/folder/example.txt; mv $_ .` ], except when there are spaces in it, it does not work.

Why doesn't $_ preserve spaces?  To see what I mean type this:

`$ echo "1" "One String Quoted"; for i in $_; do echo \"$i\"; done`
and compare with

`$ echo 1 2 "3 4 5";` **then press enter** then:  `$ for i in !*; do echo \"$i\" done;`

Can you also explain why you have to press enter ^ then do the "for" loop in order for !* to work?  [And why the $_ works without having to press enter (AKA, you can use ";" to combine the commands)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` does variable expansion while `!` is history expansion.  For `!` to access the arguments you must have added the command to the bash history, which happens on execution / when pressing enter.

Answer (score 2):

$_ preserves spaces just fine. Otherwise, it'd be giving you either a jumbled mess or just the last half of the command. What you want is to add quotes around $_ so that the command that is receiving it preserves the spaces, too.

So, in your example:

```
$ stat a\ b\ c/sub/folder/example.txt; mv "$_" .
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_` will preserve spaces fine if you quote it properly `"$_"`.  It behaves differently from the others because it's a separate mechanism from [history substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).

Another mechanism you might want to look at is the [`fc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins) command.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!#` to access parameters on the current line:

```
$ echo 1 2 "3 4 5"; for i in !#:1-3; do echo ">$i<"; done
1 2 3 4 5
>1<
>2<
>3 4 5<
```

See [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) in the bash manual.